# I'm getting an AttributeError - Python GUI Programming with Tkinter by: Alan D Moore

Tags: python, tkinter

Good day,

I'm new with Python and coding as a whole. I'm still reading, familiarizing and practicing codes from the books.
I would like to ask for your assistance how to debug the error. Please help me so that I can understand where I get it wrong.

I literally copied the code in the book. The book is Python GUI Programming with Tkinter by Alan D. Moore. But I'm getting the "AttributeError". I downloaded his source code from his github and tried it (it works!) but mine doesn't.

Here's my re-type code

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


# Start coding here

# A widget containing a label and input together

class LabelInput(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, label='', input_class=ttk.Entry,
        input_var=None, input_args=None, label_args=None,
        **kwargs):

        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        input_args = input_args or {}
        label_args = label_args or {}
        self.variable = input_var

        if input_class in (ttk.Checkbutton, ttk.Button, ttk.Radiobutton):
            input_args["text"] = label
            input_args["variable"] = input_var
        else:
            self.label = ttk.Label(self, text=label, **label_args)
            self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
            input_args["textvariable"] = input_var

        self.input = input_class(self, **input_args)
        self.input.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def grid(self, sticky=(tk.E + tk.W), **kwargs):
        super().grid(sticky=sticky, **kwargs)

    def get(self):
        try:
            if self.variable:
                return self.variable.get()
            elif type(self.input) == tk.Text:
                return self.input.get('1.0', tk.END)
            else:
                return self.input.get()
        except (TypeError, tk.TclError):
            # happens when numeric fields are empty.
            return ''

    def set(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        if type(self.variable) == tk.BooleanVar:
            self.variable.set(bool(value))
        elif self.variable:
            self.variable.set(value, *args, **kwargs)
        elif type(self.input) in (ttk.Checkbutton, ttk.Radiobutton):
            if value:
                self.input.select()
            else:
                self.input.deselect()
        elif type(self.input) == tk.Text:
            self.input.delete('1.0', tk.END)
            self.input.insert(*'1.0', value)
        else: # input must be an Entry-type widget with no variable
            self.input.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.input.insert(0, value)

class DataRecordForm(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.inputs = {}

        recordinfo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Record Information")

        self.inputs['Date'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Date", 
            input_var=tk.StringVar())
        self.inputs['Date'].grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.inputs['Time'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Time", 
            input_class=ttk.Combobox, input_var=tk.StringVar(),
            input_args={"values": ["8:00", "12:00", "16:00", "20:00"]})
        self.inputs['Time'].grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.inputs['Technician'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Technician", 
            input_var=tk.StringVar())
        self.inputs['Technician'].grid(row=0, column=2)

        # Line 2

        self.inputs['Lab'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Lab", 
            input_class=ttk.Combobox, input_var=tk.StringVar(),
            input_args={"values": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]})
        self.inputs['Lab'].grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.inputs['Plot'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Plot",
            input_class=ttk.Combobox, input_var=tk.IntVar(),
            input_args={"values": list(range(1,21))})
        self.inputs['Plot'].grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.inputs['Seed Sample'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Seed Sample",
            input_var=tk.StringVar())
        self.inputs['Seed Sample'].grid(row=1, column=2)

        recordinfo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

        # Environment Data

        environmentinfo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Environment Data")

        self.inputs['Humidity'] = LabelInput(environmentinfo, "Humidity (g/m³)",
            input_class=ttk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0.5, "to": 52.0, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Humidity'].grid(row=0, column=0)       

        self.inputs['Light'] = LabelInput(environmentinfo, "Light (klx)",
            input_class=ttk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 100, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Light'].grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.inputs['Temperature'] = LabelInput(environmentinfo, "Temperature(°C))",
            input_class=ttk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 4, "to": 40, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Temperature'].grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.inputs['Equipment Fault'] = LabelInput(environmentinfo, "Equipment Fault",
            input_class=ttk.Checkbutton, input_var=tk.BooleanVar())
        self.inputs['Equipment Fault'].grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)

        environmentinfo.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

        # Plant Data

        plantinfo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Plant Data")

        self.inputs['Plants'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Plants",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.IntVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 20})
        self.inputs['Plants'].grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.inputs['Blossoms'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Blossoms",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.IntVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000})
        self.inputs['Blossoms'].grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.inputs['Fruit'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Fruit",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.IntVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000})
        self.inputs['Fruit'].grid(row=0, column=2)      

        self.inputs['Min Height'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Min Height(cm)",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Min Height'].grid(row=1, column=0)     

        self.inputs['Max Height'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Max Height(cm)",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Max Height'].grid(row=1, column=0) 

        self.inputs['Median Height'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Median Height(cm)",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Median Height'].grid(row=1, column=0)  

        plantinfo.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

        # Notes Section

        self.inputs['Notes'] = LabelInput(self, "Notes", input_class=tk.Text,
            input_args={"width": 50, "height": 10})
        self.inputs['Notes'].grid(sticky=tk.W, row=3, column=0)

        self.reset()

        def get(self):
            data = {}
            for key, widget in self.inputs.items():
                data[key] = widget.get()
            return data

        def reset(self):
            for widget in self.inputs.values():
                widget.set('')

class Application(tk.Tk):
    """Application root window"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.title("ABC Data Entry Application")
        self.resizable(0,0)

        ttk.Label(self, text="ABC Data Entry Application", 
            font=("TkDefaultFont", 16)).grid(row=0)

        self.recordform = DataRecordForm(self)
        self.recordform.grid(row=1, padx=10)

        self.savebutton = ttk.Button(self, text="Save", command=self.on_save)
        self.savebutton.grid(sticky=tk.E, row=2, padx=10)

        # Status Bar

        self.status = tk.StringVar()
        self.statusbar = ttk.Label(self, textvar=self.status)
        self.statusbar.grid(sticky=(tk.W + tk.E), row=3, padx=10)

        self.records_saved = 0


    def on_save(self):
        datestring = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        filename = "abc_data_record_{}.csv".format(datestring)
        newfile = not os.path.exists(filename)

        data = self.recordform.get()

        with open(filename, 'a') as fh:
            csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(fn, fieldnames=data.keys())

            if newfile:
                csvwriter.writeheader()
            csvwriter.writerow(data)

        self.records_saved += 1
        self.status.set("{} records saved this session".format(self.records_saved))
        self.recordform.reset()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you show us the full traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\practice gui\ABC Data Entry\data_entry_app.py", line 229, in <module>
    app = Application()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\practice gui\ABC Data Entry\data_entry_app.py", line 195, in __init__
    self.recordform = DataRecordForm(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\practice gui\ABC Data Entry\data_entry_app.py", line 172, in __init__
    self.reset()
AttributeError: 'DataRecordForm' object has no attribute 'reset'
[Finished in 547ms]

Comment: i tried commenting Line 172 #self.reset() to test it. The GUI will display but when I tried saving it. I encounter another  AttributeError. Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\practice gui\ABC Data Entry\data_entry_app.py", line 215, in on_save
    data = self.recordform.get()
AttributeError: 'DataRecordForm' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Your functions `reset` and `get` are indented too much.

Comment: @ColBeans.Python it means that there is no `reset` function for the class `DataRecordForm`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I used TAB key when I type this in Sublime. But I always used TAB key and not 4 spaces. All of my code used TAB key. Was that the reason? Should I use 4 spaces instead?

Comment: @DaniyalWarraich I define the reset and get classes...just like what it appears in the book as well as in the source code of the author.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the input. I eventually realized I over indented it.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import csv
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


# Start coding here

# A widget containing a label and input together

class LabelInput(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, label='', input_class=ttk.Entry,
        input_var=None, input_args=None, label_args=None,
        **kwargs):

        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)
        input_args = input_args or {}
        label_args = label_args or {}
        self.variable = input_var

        if input_class in (ttk.Checkbutton, ttk.Button, ttk.Radiobutton):
            input_args["text"] = label
            input_args["variable"] = input_var
        else:
            self.label = ttk.Label(self, text=label, **label_args)
            self.label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
            input_args["textvariable"] = input_var

        self.input = input_class(self, **input_args)
        self.input.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def grid(self, sticky=(tk.E + tk.W), **kwargs):
        super().grid(sticky=sticky, **kwargs)

    def get(self):
        try:
            if self.variable:
                return self.variable.get()
            elif type(self.input) == tk.Text:
                return self.input.get('1.0', tk.END)
            else:
                return self.input.get()
        except (TypeError, tk.TclError):
            # happens when numeric fields are empty.
            return ''

    def set(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        if type(self.variable) == tk.BooleanVar:
            self.variable.set(bool(value))
        elif self.variable:
            self.variable.set(value, *args, **kwargs)
        elif type(self.input) in (ttk.Checkbutton, ttk.Radiobutton):
            if value:
                self.input.select()
            else:
                self.input.deselect()
        elif type(self.input) == tk.Text:
            self.input.delete('1.0', tk.END)
            self.input.insert(*'1.0', value)
        else: # input must be an Entry-type widget with no variable
            self.input.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.input.insert(0, value)

class DataRecordForm(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.inputs = {}

        recordinfo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Record Information")

        self.inputs['Date'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Date", 
            input_var=tk.StringVar())
        self.inputs['Date'].grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.inputs['Time'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Time", 
            input_class=ttk.Combobox, input_var=tk.StringVar(),
            input_args={"values": ["8:00", "12:00", "16:00", "20:00"]})
        self.inputs['Time'].grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.inputs['Technician'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Technician", 
            input_var=tk.StringVar())
        self.inputs['Technician'].grid(row=0, column=2)

        # Line 2

        self.inputs['Lab'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Lab", 
            input_class=ttk.Combobox, input_var=tk.StringVar(),
            input_args={"values": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]})
        self.inputs['Lab'].grid(row=1, column=0)

        self.inputs['Plot'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Plot",
            input_class=ttk.Combobox, input_var=tk.IntVar(),
            input_args={"values": list(range(1,21))})
        self.inputs['Plot'].grid(row=1, column=1)

        self.inputs['Seed Sample'] = LabelInput(recordinfo, "Seed Sample",
            input_var=tk.StringVar())
        self.inputs['Seed Sample'].grid(row=1, column=2)

        recordinfo.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

        # Environment Data

        environmentinfo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Environment Data")

        self.inputs['Humidity'] = LabelInput(environmentinfo, "Humidity (g/m³)",
            input_class=ttk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0.5, "to": 52.0, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Humidity'].grid(row=0, column=0)       

        self.inputs['Light'] = LabelInput(environmentinfo, "Light (klx)",
            input_class=ttk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 100, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Light'].grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.inputs['Temperature'] = LabelInput(environmentinfo, "Temperature(°C))",
            input_class=ttk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 4, "to": 40, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Temperature'].grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.inputs['Equipment Fault'] = LabelInput(environmentinfo, "Equipment Fault",
            input_class=ttk.Checkbutton, input_var=tk.BooleanVar())
        self.inputs['Equipment Fault'].grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)

        environmentinfo.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

        # Plant Data

        plantinfo = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Plant Data")

        self.inputs['Plants'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Plants",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.IntVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 20})
        self.inputs['Plants'].grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.inputs['Blossoms'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Blossoms",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.IntVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000})
        self.inputs['Blossoms'].grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.inputs['Fruit'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Fruit",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.IntVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000})
        self.inputs['Fruit'].grid(row=0, column=2)      

        self.inputs['Min Height'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Min Height(cm)",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Min Height'].grid(row=1, column=0)     

        self.inputs['Max Height'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Max Height(cm)",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Max Height'].grid(row=1, column=0) 

        self.inputs['Median Height'] = LabelInput(plantinfo, "Median Height(cm)",
            input_class=tk.Spinbox, input_var=tk.DoubleVar(),
            input_args={"from_": 0, "to": 1000, "increment": .01})
        self.inputs['Median Height'].grid(row=1, column=0)  

        plantinfo.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=(tk.W + tk.E))

        # Notes Section

        self.inputs['Notes'] = LabelInput(self, "Notes", input_class=tk.Text,
            input_args={"width": 50, "height": 10})
        self.inputs['Notes'].grid(sticky=tk.W, row=3, column=0)

        self.reset()

    def get(self):
        data = {}
        for key, widget in self.inputs.items():
            data[key] = widget.get()
        return data

    def reset(self):
        for widget in self.inputs.values():
            widget.set('')

class Application(tk.Tk):
    """Application root window"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.title("ABC Data Entry Application")
        self.resizable(0,0)

        ttk.Label(self, text="ABC Data Entry Application", 
            font=("TkDefaultFont", 16)).grid(row=0)

        self.recordform = DataRecordForm(self)
        self.recordform.grid(row=1, padx=10)

        self.savebutton = ttk.Button(self, text="Save", command=self.on_save)
        self.savebutton.grid(sticky=tk.E, row=2, padx=10)

        # Status Bar

        self.status = tk.StringVar()
        self.statusbar = ttk.Label(self, textvar=self.status)
        self.statusbar.grid(sticky=(tk.W + tk.E), row=3, padx=10)

        self.records_saved = 0


    def on_save(self):
        datestring = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        filename = "abc_data_record_{}.csv".format(datestring)
        newfile = not os.path.exists(filename)

        data = self.recordform.get()

        with open(filename, 'a') as fh:
            csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(fn, fieldnames=data.keys())

            if newfile:
                csvwriter.writeheader()
            csvwriter.writerow(data)

        self.records_saved += 1
        self.status.set("{} records saved this session".format(self.records_saved))
        self.recordform.reset()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()
```

Your `get` and `reset` methods were indented too much.

Comment: @DaiyalWarraich Thanks. I get it now. I eventually used TAB key twice on the said classes. Moreover, after that, I was able to detect/debug (typos) on my code. Line 61 should delete *, Line 57 should be column=1, Line 162 should be column=2, Line 219 should be fh